# How can I send an input value to the Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I would like to send a value from a form/s input field to the Redux store.
The value should be a key-value pair of an object in the store.
The only place where I stuck is how to target this object itself. dot notation is not working. Sorry, I am new to Redux. My code is:

```
 <input className="form-control mb-3" style={{ background: "white" }} 
  placeholder="Name" name="childsName" value={this.props.childName} 
  onChange={this.props.getChildName} type="text" />



  export const getChildName = (e) => dispatch => {
   dispatch({
     type: GET_CHILD_NAME,
    payload: e.target.value
   })
 }

case GET_CHILD_NAME:
  return {
    ...state,
    childInformation: action.payload
  };

const initialState = {
  childInformation: {
  checked: [],
  childName: "",
  childSurname: "",
  birthDate: ""
  }
```

};

I would like to add the value to the childInformation object's childName property

Comment: your question is not related to redux, it is the usage of spread syntax (not dot notation) to manipulate a nested attribute in the object.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. My explanation was blurry. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use spread syntax to override nested value in state and return new object:

```
case GET_CHILD_NAME:
    return {
      ...state,
      childInformation: {
         ...state.childInformation,
         childName: action.payload
      }
    };
```

Also please note that in your component this value should be probably accessed like this:
`value = {this.props.childInformation.childName}`
(But this of course depends on how you map redux state to component props in `mapStateToProps`).

Comment: Thank you very much :)) Your solution is much sophisticated than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I got it :)))

```
  export const getChildName = (e) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
   type: GET_CHILD_NAME,
  payload: {childName:e.target.value}
 })
}
```

the value had to be wrapped around curl braces.